# django render_to_response is not defined error

Tags: python, django-cms, render-to-response

Hi I am getting this error, while I tried make a simple app.

```
NameError at /first/

global name 'render_to_response' is not defined

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/first/?preview
Django Version:     1.3
Exception Type:     NameError
Exception Value:    

global name 'render_to_response' is not defined

Exception Location:     /home/naveen/django_projects/myproject/first/views.py in index, line 5
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.6
Python Path:    

['/home/naveen/django_projects/myproject',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-0.8.3-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_evolution-0.6.2-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0']

Server time:    Thu, 31 Mar 2011 14:50:32 -0500
```

any ideas?!

Comment: Could you post some of your view.py code?  The obvious answer is that `from django.shortcuts import render_to_response` is missing.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Did you try import render_to_response as `from django.shortcuts import render_to_response`?

Comment: Deprecated, see below.

Answer (score 11):

If you're reading this beyond - 2017 , don't `render_to_response` just `render`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response

```
Source - Django official documentation for version - 1.11 
" render_to_response()¶

render_to_response(template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None)[source]¶

This function preceded the introduction of render() and works similarly except that it doesn’t make the request available in the response. 
It’s not recommended and is likely to be deprecated in the future."
```

Answer (score 1):

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response is deprecated.
use django.shortcuts import render

```
def renderView(request):
input = "Best Times, render"
return render(request,'mytest/home.html',{'mytime': input})
```